# Fixing indentation of CDATA sections

Tags: xml, xslt

Im completely new to XML/XSL/XSLT, and while i have been digging msdn, 3schools.com and google for the past hour i cant figure this one out. I think is because CDATA isnt parsed by xml, but I thought that as my edit did work on the node i should be able to fix this...

Note that this is not a very important issue, I just want to learn a little bit more of XSL and what better way than fixing stuff that doesnt seem to work as i want it to.

So... my script saves options on an XML file in which i will also save some code snippets which might contain characters that need to be escaped. A small example would be:

```
<Snippet title="Version Test">
<![CDATA[
version := "AHK Version: " a_ahkversion
unicode := "& Supports Unicode: " (a_isunicode ? "Yes" : "No")
Msgbox % version "`n" unicode
]]>
</Snippet>
```

With the following xsl i get a fairly good indentation:

```
<!-- Extracted from: http://www.dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/pretty.html (v2) -->
<!-- Cdata info: http://www.altova.com/forum/default.aspx?g=posts&t=1000002342 -->
<!-- Modified By RaptorX -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" 
            indent="yes" 
            encoding="UTF-8"
            cdata-section-elements="Snippet"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="@*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates />
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="comment()|processing-instruction()">
   <xsl:copy />
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
<!-- I have to keep the indentation here in this file as 
i want it to be on the XML file -->
```

Well, basically it doesnt match CDATA sections, so googling around I found that i could do the following which helps a little but produces this output:

```
xsl:copy-of select="@*|node()" /> << -- by adding that i match cdata nodes too

Output:
<Snippet title="Version Test">
   <![CDATA[
version := "AHK Version: " a_ahkversion
unicode := "Supports Unicode: " (a_isunicode ? "Yes" : "No")
Msgbox % version "`n" unicode
   ]]></Snippet>   <<-- here is the problem I cant seem to put a newline there lol
```

So the question is:

how do i tell xsl to indent the CDATA section as it does with everything else:

```
    <root>
        <child/>
    </root>

   <Snippet title="Version Test">
   <![CDATA[
    version := "AHK Version: " a_ahkversion
    unicode := "Supports Unicode: " (a_isunicode ? "Yes" : "No")
    Msgbox % version "`n" unicode
   ]]> << --- this is what im looking for
   </Snippet>
```

Comment: Why is it important that the text be indented?  You're asking the serializer to change the document's semantics... or rather the output serializer can't know that, _in this special instance_, inserting whitespace into the middle of a text node does not change the semantics.  Suppose the CDATA section contained some Python code... inserting extra spaces at the beginning of each line would almost definitely change the semantics.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a complete and tested solution that really indents the lines of the text in the original CDATA section. An extensive explanation is also provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"
  cdata-section-elements="Snippet"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="Snippet/text()">
  <xsl:call-template name="replace"/>
  <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template name="replace">
  <xsl:param name="pText" select="."/>

  <xsl:if test="string-length($pText) >0">
   <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="not(contains($pText,'&#xA;'))">
     <xsl:value-of select="$pText"/>
    </xsl:when>

    <xsl:otherwise>
     <xsl:value-of select=
        "substring-before($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
     <xsl:text>&#xA;&#9;&#9;</xsl:text>

     <xsl:call-template name="replace">
      <xsl:with-param name="pText"
       select="substring-after($pText, '&#xA;')"/>
     </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:if>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<Snippet title="Version Test">
<![CDATA[
version := "AHK Version: " a_ahkversion
unicode := "& Supports Unicode: " (a_isunicode ? "Yes" : "No")
Msgbox % version "`n" unicode]]>
</Snippet>
```

**produces the wanted, correct result**:

```
<Snippet title="Version Test"><![CDATA[

        version := "AHK Version: " a_ahkversion
        unicode := "& Supports Unicode: " (a_isunicode ? "Yes" : "No")
        Msgbox % version "`n" unicode

]]></Snippet>
```

**Explanation**:

1. The identity rule copies every node "as-is".
2. The `cdata-section-elements="Snippet"` attribute of `<xsl:output>` instructs the XSLT processor to serialize any text node of any `Snippet` element as a CDATA section.
3. There is a single template that overrides the identity template -- when matching a text node that is a child of a `Snippet` element.
4. The processing of any such text-node is done by calling the `replace` template, which replaces any NL character with NL followed by two tab characters. When these replacements are done, one last NL character is output, so that the end tag `</Snippet>` will be on a new line.

Comment: +1 Yes. This seems more appropiated answer. Although identation should take ancestors into account, at least for the majority of XSLT processor (not MSXSL).

Comment: @Alejandro: Please, stop deleting your answers after even the slightest comment :( ... or I'll be afraid to point out any issues in your answers -- you could just correct your answer. As for indentation... well, we must have a Javascript parser in order to perform properly the indentation of a Javascript program.

Answer (score 0):

This is kludgy but it should work and is super quick.  Simply use `<xsl:text>`:

```
<xsl:copy />
<xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
```

Comment: I think it's not wise to output some character (NL, `#xA`) without being readable.

Comment: @Alejandro:  Like I said, it's kludgy.